# Does magnific-popup have a draggable option

Tags: jquery, user-interface, draggable, magnific-popup

I would like to make my magnific popup draggable to allow the user to view the screen behind them.
( I saw it available in other popup but considering the simplicity yet richness of magnific-popup, I'm staying with it).

Also, is there an option to allow the user to scroll the screen behind the popup?

Thanks,

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? After a user opens an image in the gallery/view i wanted it to be draggable too.

Comment: @Noitidart I used jQuery.ui.draggable for the draggable feature.

Comment: Thanks @R.Mo ! can you please share your github repository or something of the code? :)

Comment: @Noitidart here is a very simple example
 $('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image'
}).draggable();

Answer (score 1):

I used jQuery.ui.draggable for the draggable feature.
Here is a very simple example

```
$('.test-popup-link').magnificPopup({ type: 'image' }).draggable();
```